# image is been cut at bottom when viewed in a circle using css

Tags: css

I am trying to view a user's profile photo in a circle using this css code:

```css
.circle {
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
     -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
     -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    .circle img{
        width:100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class='circle'>
    <img src='https://static.pexels.com/photos/2438/nature-forest-waves-trees.jpg'>
        </div>
```

Problem is, the image is being cut at the bottom:

[image]

Yet I expected the image to display in a full circle. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's because you haven't used a square image!  Either use a square image or make the min height and min-width:100% and put overflow:hidden on the parent

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that works on all browsers, I think `object-fit` would work great here to deal with cases where images have different proportions but like all good things, it doesn't work in IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, you need to use a square image if you want the whole image to be shown, otherwise you need to make the shortest side of the image 100% - in this case the image is landscape so you need to make the height 100% so the extra width will be hidden:

```css
.circle {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle'>
  <img src='https://static.pexels.com/photos/2438/nature-forest-waves-trees.jpg'>
</div>
```

Comment: downvoter care to comment? I have filled the circle and kept the aspect ratio of the original image.  Even the accepted answer hasn't managed that

Comment: Making a static decision to make one side longer than another isn't really a great way of doing this.  I would look at some of the other solutions which are able to dynamically size a non-square image to fit.

Comment: @DerekBrown he wanted a solution, is this not a solution - what is up with changing width:100% to height:100% - it is a solution and people like you who downvote correct answers are ruining this site.  Just because you do not agree with how to do it does not make it incorrect and worthy of a downvote.  I feel your background image answer is a hack too - you would not be able to print out the image by using making it a background image, but you don't see me downvoting your answer

Comment: a large part of StackOverflow is to create documentation for people wanting to solve these problems in the future.  Your solution is only applicable to this image because the width is larger than the height, and would not work for other images, dynamic usecases, or people who don't want cropping.

Comment: your answer is also factually inaccurate. "you need to use a square image if you want the whole image to be shown" is not true- there are a number of other answers which demonstrate this.

Comment: also to answer your previous question- you can set the background in html using `style`.

Comment: okay! enough with the... your answers are all acceptable, the good thing here is that my code is now working fine which we should all rejoice with that. Is that okay now?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in IE then [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) is a great way to make sure that the image will always cover the available space while at the same time keeping its proportions.

```css
.avatar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/2438/nature-forest-waves-trees.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="avatar">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504125130065-19cd3d71c27a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2134&q=60&cs=tinysrgb" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is not supported in IE.  I think the `background-image` approach I discussed above would be better for browser compatibility. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: Yes, I did mention the lack of IE support in my answer, it's up to the poster if he wants to support outdated browsers or not and make a choice accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

By default `img` tags take their size from the size of the image file.  In this case, the image was larger than 200x200, and so the image extended below the size of your `div`. By adding `height: 100%` to the `img` tag as well, the issue is resolved.

```css
.circle {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle'>
  <img src='https://static.pexels.com/photos/2438/nature-forest-waves-trees.jpg'>
</div>
```

Note that the above answer **stretches the image** to be 200x200.  If you don't want this stretching, I would use `background-image` instead:

```css
.circle {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;

  background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/2438/nature-forest-waves-trees.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle'>
</div>
```

Comment: That stretches the image, which is rarely a desired result.

Comment: @DBS no it doesn't- as the outer div has a fixed size, which is identical to the proportions of the image.

Comment: Erm... It definitely does. You're forcing a non-square image to display at 200x200, you can see it in your example (That image doesn't display vertical stretching very well, but swap it out and you'll see what I mean)

Comment: @DBS in that case I can edit to use `background-image` instead.  That is what I would have done anyway...